# Nginx virtual host does not work after reinstalling ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx

I had set up an Nginx virtual host serving a SPA, working just fine in Ubuntu 16.

After doing a format and installing Ubuntu 22 and Nginx, I copied my virtual host file from /etc/nginx/sites-available folder which I had kept before formatting, and remade the required symlink to sites-enabled/ folder. But it does not work (I am getting "This site can’t be reached" message by different browsers).

Syntax and status checks are ok. The default Nginx page in port 80 is there. I have restarted Nginx as well as my pc multiple times to exclude any weird caching scenarios.

I do `sudo ufw app list` and the results are (I guess) ok (CUPS, Nginx Full, Nginx HTTP, Nginx HTTPS).

My /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file is the following:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
  worker_connections 768;
  # multi_accept on;
}

http {
  
  ##
  # Basic Settings
  ##

  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;

  tcp_nodelay on;
  keepalive_timeout 65;

  types_hash_max_size 2048;
  # server_tokens off;

  server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
  # server_name_in_redirect off;

  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;

  ##
  # SSL Settings
  ##

  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

  ##
  # Logging Settings
  ##

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

  ##
  # Gzip Settings
  ##

  gzip on;

  # gzip_vary on;
  # gzip_proxied any;
  # gzip_comp_level 6;
  # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
  # gzip_http_version 1.1;
  # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json 
  application/javascript text/xml application/xml 
  application/xml+rss text/javascript;

  ##
  # Virtual Host Configs
  ##

  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

What might be going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was in the files ownership. At first I had changed the ownership to `www-data user` only at the last `/path` folder in `/home/my_user/parent/file/path`, but nginx demands that its user has ownership of the first ancestor directory of the path. Namely, when I did

```
sudo chown -R www-data:data /home/*
```

the `index.html` file in the last folder of the path was served normally.

But since I didn't want my_user to loose access to its files, I switched back the directory's ownership to my_user and I changed the nginx user, replacing the first line of `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file with:

```
user my_user;
```

After that, `index.html` was served without any more problems.